# Dropdown with Date values is submitted incorrectly

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Hi i got a dropdown of dates

```
ViewBag.fyDropdown = new SelectList(db.FinancialYear, "ID", "FY");
```

ID is the date.

I am displaying it in the view

```
@Html.DropDownList("fyDropdown")
```

my controller

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? fyDropdown)
```

In database I have "01/04/2014" Month(date) returns 4 in SQL

the URL after submitting the form is

```
ResourceProjectedCapacity?MeetingID=&fyDropdown=01%2F04%2F2014+00%3A00%3A00
```

And in controller this get translated as Month = 1, Day = 4

Comment: Seems like a culture issue. `DD/MM/YYYY` is UK format. You can use [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213505.aspx) in SQL to format the date for your desired culture, you should then get the correct results. Or just set the date time culture.

Comment: Hard-coding the format won't solve anything. The correct way to write culture-invariant code is to send the date to the server as a date parameter and avoid unnecessary conversions completely. You'll even get a performance boost because you send less data without making any conversions

Answer (score 0):

Yeap it is a culture issue.

I declared is as string and then

```
 Datetime FY = DateTime.Parse(FYDropdown);
```